# What this role of the array "menu" ? I know how constuctor works but not sure why this array "menu" has same as the class name

Tags: java, android

What this role of the array `menu` ? I know how constructor works but not sure why this array "menu" has same as the class name:

```
public class Menu {

private String name;
private String description;
// what is the role of this static array??
// why its name is same as of the class ??

public static final Menu[] menus={
new Menu ("Breakfast", "brownrice \n Bread\n Coffee"),
new Menu ("lunch", "white rice \n Bread\n Coffee"),
new Menu ("dinner", "brownrice \n Bread\n Coffee"),

};
private Menu (String name, String description)
{
    this.name=name;
    this.description= description;
}
public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
}

//any leads would be appreciated
```

Answer (score 0):

Reason for making static can be reuse of the same array name in other files.
If you could explain me the project that you are doing, i would be able to tell more .

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static final Menu[] menus={
    new Menu ("Breakfast", "brownrice \n Bread\n Coffee"),
    new Menu ("lunch", "white rice \n Bread\n Coffee"),
    new Menu ("dinner", "brownrice \n Bread\n Coffee"),
```

Above lines are creating an static array of type Menu which will be accessible  by variable name 'menus', means each element in array will be holding an reference of 'Menu' object. Since it is static array and it is not the part of instance variable, you can access it directly using class name 
    example (Suppose your class name is Demo):

```
        //accessing menu object at 0th position in array in class Demo
        Menu firstElement= Demo.menus[0];  
        //accessing 2nd element
        Menu secondElement= Demo.menus[1];
```

**why its name is same as of the class?**

well you can give it any name you like, example 'menuArray' or simple 'array'         or any other name as you like but type needs to be

```
    Menu[]    array;//Array name 'array' of type Menu
```

Comment: Thanks @dharam. This is an helpful reply :)